# Generating Function for Integer compositions with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, groups-enumeration

Find the generating function for compositions of n in which each part is at least 3, and the number of parts is at most 100.

So what I've tried is making the set of allowed parts P = {3,4,5,.....}, which leads to the generating function x^3/(1-x) . Then, I would have the sum from k=0 to 100 of (x^3/(1-x))^k which is my attempt of getting all lengths of the composition at most 100. I cant seem to go further then this and wanted tips on how to approach this and where my approach may be problematic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct.  Now use the formula for a finite geometric series, with $r=x^3/(1-x)$.

Comment: Thank you! My brain was wandering to string lemma for some reason.